# How to implement abstract factory method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, factory-method

So how to use abstract factory method in JavaScript? For example in Java:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    abstract String bar();

    public String foo() {
        return bar();
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    @Override
    String bar() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SubClass().foo());
    }
}
```

It shows `bar` and just fine. But when I tried this in JavaScript:

```
var SuperClass = function () {};
SuperClass.prototype.foo = function () {
    return this.prototype.bar();
};

var SubClass = function () {};
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

SubClass.prototype.bar = function () {
    return "bar";
};

var myClass = new SubClass();
console.log(myClass.foo());
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`. I tracked the bug and turns out, when `SuperClass.prototype.foo` is being executed, `SubClass.prototype` is still `undefined`.

So, what's the right way to do that? Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the prototype of an object through the __proto__ field.
So, if you change :

```
SuperClass.prototype.foo = function () {
    return this.prototype.bar();
};
```

with :

```
SuperClass.prototype.foo = function () {
    return this.__proto__.bar();

};
```

your example works.
You can also use:

```
return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).bar();
return this.constructor.prototype.bar();
```

But, you can just call `return this.bar()` and the prototype traversal will be executed automatically by Javascript, until the method is found in the prototype chain.

Comment: I've just realize that it's a stupid question but still thanks for answering!

Comment: and even more important, by using `this.bar()` the scope in `bar()` will be set to the current instance instead of the prototype-object. Wich might be important when you access properties of `this`, and even more important when you modify them.

Comment: @Thomas, well said! I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @RaptisDimos or you use `.call(this)` for that purpose, instead of a plain function-call

Comment: @Thomas how bar()'s scope is set to current instance is, when you create a new instance of the class all the prototypes properties will be copied to the new instance.That's how bar can be able to access current instance's data

Comment: @sundar, that's incorrect. If you call a function on an object (like `obj.fn()` or `obj["fn"]()` or even `arr[0]()`) the scope will be assigned to that object (unless the scope has been bound). The way this function ended up there doesn't matter at all. (manually adding it, or by inheritance). And the prototypes properties ARE NOT copied to the instances! That's the major difference of prototypal inheritance. That's the reason why all changes to the prototype are instantly available on all objects that inherit it.

Comment: @Thomas if you need a proof, create an instance of the object and see that instance's proto link.All the methods of parent object will be there.This is point is shared by john resig.I am happy to accept your point if there is any proofs

Comment: @sundar, the `hasOwnProperty()`-method is the proof, the distinction between own and inherited methods. The fact, that if you assign a different `__proto__` to your object, all your inherited methods are gone. You might think of it as kind of a [Proxy()](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) behind the scenes, that routes the property-get or funtion-calls up the prototype-chain, if it is not available on the current instance. assignments on the other hand are executed on the current object; and now it has this property itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should not access `bar` on the prototype. Just access it on the instance:

```
return this.bar();
```